# Default device name for qemu Slirp network

Tags: qemu, tcpdump

I am trying to redirect host's tcp port to guest's port with command from this [tutorial](http://wiki.qemu-project.org/Documentation/Networking)

**Command:**

```
-netdev user,id=mynet0,hostfwd=tcp::7777-:1234
```

**Result:**

```
Warning: netdev mynet0 has no peer
```

How do I determine which devices I have by default to set the id parameter? Or should I create some device first?

I mean what should I put instead of "mynet0"?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! The link to the tutorial you are attempting to follow appears to be missing. Please [edit] your post to provide clarity in order to help us help you!

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, fixed the link

Comment: Just a stab in th dark here, but I don't think the id=mynet0 is the problem. If the command you posted is the exact command that you used I would assume it far more likely that  you need the actual host IP and port as well as the actual guest IP and Port. What you call something isn't near as important as connection details.

Comment: I've tried this command with default IPs (it seems it can be empty so the command will look for ports at local host) and real ports, but I am getting the error like Warning: netdev mynet0 has no peer, added this info to the question

Comment: You may have noticed that the syntax you are using from the tutorial you linked is on the ToDo list rather than part of the instructions. I recommend that you revisit the documentation and try again from the top. IF this post no longer reflects current conditions, please [edit] into your post the exact commands you have tried and the results in the form **Command** `command you ran` **Result** (error output or other result) so that we can easily follow the path you ahve traveled. Thank you for helping us help you!